# I am trying to even spaced links in bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am looking for a way to easily utilize Bootstraps navbar but be able to instead of using

`class="navbar-right"` 
or `class="navbar-left"`

I would like to be able to have the links to be evenly spaced across the view instead of always having to choose a side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like [this](https://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/GEYeyo)? Try your own *.navbar-justified* class with flex:

```
.navbar-justified {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  float: none;
}
```